# Access Google AppScript API from Chrome Extension leads to 403 error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script-api

I would like to edit my Google Doc using a Google AppScript function externally via a Google Chrome extension.
To achieve this I have performed the following steps:

1. setup the script via Google Docs `Tools > Script Editor`
2. implementation of the dummy function "myFunction" with the body

```
var body = DocumentApp.openById(<docId>).getBody()
body.appendParagraph("Another paragraph.")
```

3. adding the Google Cloud Project ID in the script editor under `Resources > Cloud Platform Project` (the ID is identical to the ID I use in the Chrome Extension; the project also has Script API permissions).
4. publishing the script via `Publish > Executable API` in the script.
5. adding oauth2 in the manifest.json of the Chrome Extension.
6. initialize the gapi JavascriptBrowser client in a background script in the Chrome Extension with valid `apiKey` and `discoveryDoc`.

```
// gapi is available in global scope
gapi.load('client', async () => {
    await gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: '<apiKey>',
        discoveryDocs: ['https://script.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'],
    })

    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, async (token) => {
        // set my valid oauth token here
        gapi.auth.setToken({
            access_token: token,
        })
    })
})
```

7. calling `scripts.run`:

```
await gapi.client.script.scripts.run({
    scriptId: <scriptId>,
    resource: {
        function: 'myFunction'
    }
})
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message when running the script:

```
{
    code: 403,
    message: "Requests to this API script method google.discovery.Discovery.GetDiscoveryRest are blocked."
    status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

To make sure I didn't miss anything, I tried to call the Google Script API via Postman. I used the endpoint `https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/{scriptId}:run` and the valid oauth2 token of the Chrome Extension. This worked successfully.

Additionally, I tried to change the `discoveryDoc' URL in the initialization function on https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/script/v1/rest?version=v1 - here a similar error occurs at a later time.

```
{
    code: 403,
    message: "Requests to this API script method google.apps.script.v1.ScriptExecution.Execute are blocked"
    status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I am at a loss.

Comment: *`discoveryDoc' URL in the initialization function on https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/script/v1/rest?version=v1 - here a similar error occurs at a later time.* Could you expound on that a bit more in your question?

Comment: @TheMaster Sure, I have just updated the questions.

Comment: Could you try other api methods, say people api or maps api from `gapi`?

Comment: Already worked with sheets + docs via gapi - it works without any problems

Comment: @Druux - do not know if this is still relevant for you, but could you please expand on point #6 in the question? The error likely occursed because of (please note - not "due to") the `gapi.client.init()` call failing - can you show us the snippet?

Comment: @OlegValter - sure, I have just updated my question. Hope it helps. Please reach out if you need more context.

Comment: @Druux - thank you. Let's try this: load the library with `client:auth2`. Then, get the token with `getAuthToken` from the identity toolkit and in the callback initialize the library like this: `gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: apiKey,
            discoveryDocs: discoveryDocs,
            clientId: clientId,
            scope: scopes
        })`. Can you try that and update the question with the results?